# How to perform efficient concatentation (merge) in Python

Tags: python, merge, concatenation, memory-efficient

I have about 50 big dataset that have about 200K-500K number of columns and I am trying to think of a way to merge/concatenate these dataset efficiently. What is the fastest way to do conditional column concatenation (merging) of these files?

Currently, I have a code that works that is listed below but this code takes several hours(at least 12 hours) to do the job for my dataset. Keeping in mind that these input files(datasets) will be extremely large, is there any way to tweak this code to use as minimum memory as possible? One clue I came up with (from looking at my code below) is to close files after opening them, but I am not sure how to do that.

```
Note that:
a.  All files have the same number of rows
b.  The first two columns are the same throughout the files
c.  All files are tab delimited
d.  This code works but it is ridiculously slow!
```

My code stated below works for the sample dataset. Like my large datasets the data sets below have the same first two columns. I appreciate any feedback or suggestion on how to make the code run efficiently or alternative methods to do the job efficiently.

```
Input 1: test_c1_k2_txt.gz :-
c1  c2  1.8 1.9 1.7
L1  P   0.5 1.4 1.1
L2  P   0.4 1.8 1.2
L3  P   0.1 1.9 1.3

Input 2: test_c1_k4_txt.gz :-
c1  c2  0.1 0.9 1.1 1.2
L1  P   1.8 1.7 1.8 2.8
L2  P   1.3 1.4 1.2 1.1
L3  P   1.7 1.6 1.5 1.4

Input 3: test_c3_k1_txt.gz :-
c1  c2  1.3 1.4
L1  P   1.1 2.9
L2  P   2.2 1.4
L3  P   1.7 1.6

Output : - test_all_c_all_k_concatenated.txt.gz :-
c1  c2  1.8 1.9 1.7 0.1 0.9 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4
L1  P   0.5 1.4 1.1 1.8 1.7 1.8 2.8 1.1 2.9
L2  P   0.4 1.8 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.2 1.1 2.2 1.4
L3  P   0.1 1.9 1.3 1.7 1.6 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.6
```

Python Code for Merging/Concatenation

```
import os,glob,sys,gzip,time


start_time=time.time()

max_c=3
max_k=4

filearr=[]

# Loop through the files, in the order of “c” first and then in the order of “k” and create a file array
for c in range(1,max_c):
    for k in range(1,max_k):
    # Set my string of file name
        fname= "test_c"+str(c)+"_k"+str(k)+"_txt.gz"
    # If the file name specified exists, ..
        if os.path.exists(fname):
            print ("Input file "+ fname+ " exists ... ")
        # Open files and create a list array
            files=[gzip.open(f) for f in glob.glob(fname)]
        filearr=filearr+files

# Initialize a list array to append columns to
d=[]
for file in filearr:
    # row strip each line for each file
    row_list=[line.rstrip().split('\t') for line in file.readlines()]
    # Transpose the list array to make columns for each file
    row_list_t=[[r[col] for r in row_list] for col in range(len(row_list[0]))]
    # Combine the transposed rows from each file into one file
    d=d+row_list_t

# Initialize an empty array
temp=[]
for i in (d):
        # Append new columns each time
    if i not in temp:
         temp.append(i)
appended=[[r[col] for r in temp] for col in range(len(temp[0]))]

# Write output dataset into a tab delimited file
outfile=gzip.open('all_c_all_k_concatenated.txt.gz','w')
for i in appended:
    for j in i[:-1]:
        outfile.write(j+'\t')
    outfile.write(i[-1]+'\n')
outfile.close()
print 'executed prob file concatenation sucessfully. '

total_time=time.time() - start_time
print "Total time it took to finish: ", total_time
```

Comment: you need to locate the bottle neck figure out which parts are taking a long time ... (eg put timers(or even better use cprofile) around each step (maybe even turn each step into functions(not that that will result in any kind of speedup, it just makes it more readable...)))   (I didnt downvote ... but the person who did probably did so because this really belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'd wager that it was spending all its time doing the `if i not in temp:` check; `temp` is a list, and so membership testing is worst-case O(N), which means the whole loop will be `O(N^2)`.

Comment: also OP should use meaningful variable names `d` tells is nothing ... `i,j` are typically indices, but you are using them as values ...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that this post shouldn't belong in stack overflow. Thank you, these are helpful comments. I estimated how long each block (each step) takes to run, and it seems that for loop that transposes each matrix takes the longest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is an efficient way to handle the data merge problem.  It opens all the files.  Then it copies the first line from the first data file -- this is the two column header plus all the values.  Next, for each input file except for the first, it reads a line, zaps the first two header columns, and writes it to the output dataset.  Each input file's values are separated from the others.

Have fun!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import glob, gzip, re

data_files = [ gzip.open(name) for name in sorted(
    glob.glob('*_txt.gz')
) ]

# we'll use the two header columns from the first file
firstf = data_files.pop(0)

outf = gzip.open('all_c_all_k_concatenated.txt.gz', 'w')
for recnum,fline in enumerate( firstf ):

    print 'record', recnum+1

    # output header columns plus first batch of data
    outf.write( fline.rstrip() )

    # separate first file's values from others
    outf.write( ' ' )

    # for each input, read one line of data, write values
    for dataf in data_files:
        # read line with headers and values
        line = dataf.next()

        # zap two header columns
        line = re.sub(r'^\S+\s+\S+\s+', '', line)

        outf.write( line.rstrip() )

        # separate this file's values from next
        outf.write( ' ' )

    # finish the line of data
    outf.write( '\n' )

outf.close()
```

Comment: This is really helpful, less costly in memory, more efficient but still takes as long as the above code. Here is a revised version of yours. I changed it because first, it is not ordering the files correctly (I want the files in order of c and then k), so I wrote another for loop to create an array of files. Second, the format of the output was not right, so I inserted tab instead of spaces when writing the file:

Answer (score 0):

Your code is hard to read; however, I can see two O(N^2) operations being performed here.

The first is where you perform `d = d + row_list_t` inside of a loop. That operations creates a new list each time so it is O(N) which makes the loop it is in O(N^2). Switch to using the append method to improve this.

The second is where you perform `if i not in temp:`. Searching a list is O(N) which makes your loop O(N^2). Add the use of a set to use for existence checking to fix this. (The extra O(N) memory required is nothing compared to what is already being used) and worth it for the speedup.

However this may not fix all of your problems; there could well be more, so the best thing you could do would be to `import time` at the start of your program and then call `print time.time()` before each section of your program. This will give you an idea of what parts are running slower than the rest and you can try to figure out what to do to fix them.